# How to create text boxes and buttons dynamically and get the value from each text box in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dynamic, textbox

I'm trying to build tables dynamically with a text box and a button in each table. The tables are added successfully but when I pressed on the button it made a post back to the page and the tables were gone. So i build each table inside an updatePanel but when a button was clicked twice, a postback was occurred again.How can I prevent the potback? and then,  how do I get the value inside the text boxes? TNX very much!

```
private void addTable(List<fileSaving> fs)
{  
    foreach (fileSaving f in fs){
    UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
    up.ID = "UpdatePanel-"+f.FileName;
    up.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
    Table T = new Table();
    T.CssClass = "filesTBL";

    TableRow hTR = new TableRow();

    TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
    Image fileImg = new Image();
    fileImg.ImageUrl = "images/"+f.FileExtension+".png";
    td1.Controls.Add(fileImg);
    hTR.Cells.Add(td1);

    TableCell td2 = new TableCell();
    td2.Text = f.ExpName;
    hTR.Cells.Add(td2);

    TableCell td3 = new TableCell();
    Image expImg = new Image();
    expImg.ImageUrl = "images/magnet.png";
    td3.Controls.Add(expImg);
    hTR.Cells.Add(td3);

    T.Rows.Add(hTR);

    TableRow mTR = new TableRow();

    TableCell td4 = new TableCell();
    td4.Text = "";
    mTR.Cells.Add(td4);

    TableCell td5 = new TableCell();
    td5.Text = f.TeamID.ToString();
    mTR.Cells.Add(td5);

    TableCell td6 = new TableCell();
    Image teamImg = new Image();
    teamImg.ImageUrl = "images/team3.png";
    td6.Controls.Add(teamImg);
    mTR.Cells.Add(td6);

    T.Rows.Add(mTR);
    TableRow lTR = new TableRow();

    TableCell td7 = new TableCell();
    HyperLink downloadLink = new HyperLink();
    downloadLink.Attributes.Add("href", "http://proj.ruppin.ac.il/igroup39/test2/tar5/tar5.zip");
    downloadLink.ImageUrl = "images/download2.png";
    downloadLink.ToolTip = "לחץ להורדה";
    td7.Controls.Add(downloadLink);
    lTR.Cells.Add(td7);

    TableCell td8 = new TableCell();
    if (f.ReportGrade != -1)
    {
        td8.Text = f.ReportGrade.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.ID = f.FileName + "-tb";
        gFN = tb.ID;
        tb.Width = 40;
        td8.Controls.Add(tb);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = f.FileName + "-btn";
        btn.Text = "הזן ציון";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        td8.Controls.Add(btn);

    }

    lTR.Cells.Add(td8);

    TableCell td9 = new TableCell();
    Image gradeImg = new Image();
    gradeImg.ImageUrl = "images/grade.png";
    td9.Controls.Add(gradeImg);
    lTR.Cells.Add(td9);

    T.Rows.Add(lTR);
    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(T);
    Page.Form.Controls.Add(up);
    }

}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Button mybtn = (Button)sender;
        Response.Write(mybtn.ID);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify two items for me? First, why did you add the UpdatePanel? Does it solve a specific problem, or is it just something you want as part of the functional design of the page? Second, what exactly is the issue with the button being clicked twice? I would expect a button click to cause a postback.Is it causing a problem?

Comment: As far as the broader question, the major sticking point you're likely running into is one of timing. When is your `addTable()` method called? Postback data and viewstate information is bound to controls _after_ `Init` but _before_ `Load`; as such, it's important that you call `addTable()` during your `Init` event. Control events are then fired immediately after `Load`. MSDN has a good article summarizing the [ASP.NET Web Forms Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472).

Comment: I added the update panel because I wanted to prevent the refrefsh for the page when the button was clicked. But it dosent solved the problem...

Comment: And yes I would like the click to cause a postback buy not to refresh the whole page. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used an `UpdatePanel`, but I _believe_ the partial refresh functionality will fail if any aspect of the viewstate or control hierarchy is modified outside of the `UpdatePanel` (which makes sense when you think about it). Given this, the fact that you're adding dynamically created `UpdatePanel` controls to your form each postback may be causing issues. Is it possible for you instead to have a single declaratively defined `UpdatePanel` and then add your table controls to that?

Comment: Hi, I tried this but i acted in the same way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long time thinking how to solved this, with help from some friend, I wrote this in `page_load` so when the button was pressed and postback occurred the page rebuild my dynamic controls, but only the button press- this is the role of the `session`.
My new code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {

        if (Session["showFiles"] != null)
        {
            bool flag = (bool)Session["showFiles"];
            if (flag == true)
            {
                fileSaving fs = new fileSaving();
                List<fileSaving> fileslist = fs.filesList(hiddenLBL.Text);
                addTable(fileslist);
            }
        }
    }
    ExpScheduleClass ESCC = new ExpScheduleClass();
    List<string> labCourses = ESCC.getCourseList();
    // dynamically create a dropdown list (aka DDL)
    DDLCourses = new DropDownList();
    DDLCourses.DataSource = labCourses; // set the data source
    DDLCourses.DataBind(); // bind the data to the DDL control
    DDLCourses.AutoPostBack = true;
    DDLCourses.SelectedIndexChanged += DDLCourses_SelectedIndexChanged;
    coursePH.Controls.Add(DDLCourses);

}

private void DDLCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] coursesIDArr = DDLCourses.SelectedValue.Split(' ');
    /* courseLBL.Text = coursesIDArr[0];
     string courseID = coursesIDArr[0];//take the id from the list*/
    courseLBL.Text = coursesIDArr[2];
    classLBL.Text = coursesIDArr[4];
    currnetYearLBL.Text = coursesIDArr[6];
    semesterLBL.Text = coursesIDArr[8];
    courseLBL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    currnetYearLBL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    semesterLBL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    classLBL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    ExpScheduleClass SIEGL = new ExpScheduleClass();
    List<String> lessonsList = SIEGL.getLessonList(coursesIDArr[2]);
    DDLLessons.DataSource = lessonsList; // set the data source
    DDLLessons.DataBind();
}

protected void DDLLessons_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] lessonsIdArr = DDLLessons.SelectedValue.Split(' ');
    string lessonID = lessonsIdArr[0];
    lessonLBL.Text = lessonID;
    dateLBL.Text = lessonsIdArr[1];
    lessonLBL.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    hiddenLBL.Text = lessonID;
    fileSaving fs = new fileSaving();
    List<fileSaving> fileslist = fs.filesList(lessonID);
    addTable(fileslist);
    Session["showFiles"] = true;

}
private void addTable(List<fileSaving> fs)
{
    foreach (fileSaving f in fs)
    {
        UpdatePanel up = new UpdatePanel();
        up.ID = "UpdatePanel-" + f.FileName;
        up.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        Table T = new Table();
        T.CssClass = "filesTBL";

        //------------Header Row------------------------------------------------
        TableRow hTR = new TableRow();

        TableCell td1 = new TableCell();
        Image fileImg = new Image();
        fileImg.ImageUrl = "images/" + f.FileExtension + ".png";
        td1.Controls.Add(fileImg);
        hTR.Cells.Add(td1);

        TableCell td2 = new TableCell();
        td2.Text = f.ExpName;
        hTR.Cells.Add(td2);

        TableCell td3 = new TableCell();
        Image expImg = new Image();
        expImg.ImageUrl = "images/magnet.png";
        td3.Controls.Add(expImg);
        hTR.Cells.Add(td3);

        T.Rows.Add(hTR);

        //------------Middle Row------------------------------------------------
        TableRow mTR = new TableRow();

        TableCell td4 = new TableCell();
        td4.Text = "";
        mTR.Cells.Add(td4);

        TableCell td5 = new TableCell();
        td5.Text = f.TeamID.ToString();
        mTR.Cells.Add(td5);

        TableCell td6 = new TableCell();
        Image teamImg = new Image();
        teamImg.ImageUrl = "images/team3.png";
        td6.Controls.Add(teamImg);
        mTR.Cells.Add(td6);

        T.Rows.Add(mTR);
        //------------Last Row------------------------------------------------
        TableRow lTR = new TableRow();

        TableCell td7 = new TableCell();
        HyperLink downloadLink = new HyperLink();
        //downloadLink.Attributes.Add("href", "/igroup39/test2/project/reportFiles/" + f.FileName);
        downloadLink.Attributes.Add("href", "http://proj.ruppin.ac.il/igroup39/test2/tar5/tar5.zip");
        downloadLink.ImageUrl = "images/download2.png";
        downloadLink.ToolTip = "לחץ להורדה";
        td7.Controls.Add(downloadLink);
        lTR.Cells.Add(td7);

        TableCell td8 = new TableCell();
        if (f.ReportGrade != -1)
        {
            td8.Text = f.ReportGrade.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = f.FileName + "-tb";
            gFN = tb.ID;
            tb.Width = 40;
            td8.Controls.Add(tb);

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.ID = f.FileName + "-btn";
            btn.Text = "הזן ציון";
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
            td8.Controls.Add(btn);

        }

        lTR.Cells.Add(td8);

        TableCell td9 = new TableCell();
        Image gradeImg = new Image();
        gradeImg.ImageUrl = "images/grade.png";
        td9.Controls.Add(gradeImg);
        lTR.Cells.Add(td9);

        T.Rows.Add(lTR);
        up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(T);
        Page.Form.Controls.Add(up);
        //filesTablesPH.Controls.Add(up);
    }

}

protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button mybtn = (Button)sender;
    string btnID = mybtn.ID;
    string[] file_Name = btnID.Split('-');
    string tbID = file_Name[0] + "-tb";
    string grade = ((TextBox)filesTablesPH.FindControl(tbID)).Text;
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert("+grade+")", true);
}
```

Comment: Congratulations on getting the issue resolved, and apologies for not being able to provide more insight.

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you're not simply declaratively adding the controls to, for instance, a `ListView` (or some other repeater) and then binding your data to the controls within that? I didn't want to bring this up previously because it's independent of your question, but I was curious since this approach, to me, seems much harder to read and maintain.

Comment: Well, I guess you're right, but I didn't know what a `ListView` is. I'll use `ListView` next time for something similar. Anyway, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Ultimately, it doesn't matter; they're functionally the same. But I personally find the declarative format to be a lot easier to read, and it usually requires a lot fewer lines of code.